# stream AAD sign-in logs to Eventhub and then reads log data from an event hub and forwards it to a specific endpoint exposed by Splunk

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub

I have a requirement where we need to stream AAD sign-in logs to Eventhub and then reads log data from an event hub and forwards it to a specific endpoint exposed by Splunk.

I believe below are the Azure components that are involved 
AAD
Event HUb
Function App
Storage Account

Could you please specify in detail the steps involved on achieving this.

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft has documentation on streaming AAD logs to Event Hubs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/tutorial-azure-monitor-stream-logs-to-event-hub). Documentation on integrating AAD logs with Splunk can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/tutorial-integrate-activity-logs-with-splunk).

Comment: I tried following the first link, but I dont see any incoming messages coming to the event hub.

Comment: Here's what I did, but still no luck
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60169552/no-incoming-messages-to-event-hub/60174614#60174614